# Allowing SSH To use ssh-agent in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, ssh-keys, shell-scripting, ssh-agent

I am working on recon for a set of systems my company is taking over and they use a different authentication method than we do. Specifically we use AD auth and a jump server to access systems where they use a mix of Keys, passphrases and others for various systems.

For systems that use an SSH key I am trying to write a script that allows me to automate a login and run a command to retrieve data. My key has a password on it and thus I am trying to leverage ssh-agent to allow my script the ability to authenticate to the systems with little to no input.

So far it seems the issue is when I run something like the following, ssh-agent either A.) Dies and ends before my for loop, or B.) prints the commands for environment variables and doesn't pull them into the scope.

```
eval ssh-agent
ssh-add ~/.ssh/${USER}_mvc

for i in `cat ${HOSTLIST}`
do
     ssh -l ${USER} ${i} -t 'uname -r' 
     &>${OUTDIR}/${i}.keyauthcollector
done
```

I know I'm missing something to pull in the variables SSH Agent generates but I can't seem to find it and of course all the scripts I find when searching google for SSH-Agent scripting help are looking to make ssh-agent run for your current session not a script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [man page for ssh-agent](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-agent) explains what was missing:

> There are two main ways to get an agent set up:
>
> The first is that the agent starts a new subcommand into which some environment variables are exported, eg `ssh-agent xterm &`.
>
> The second is that the agent prints the needed shell commands (either sh(1) or csh(1) syntax can be generated) which can be evaluated in the calling shell, eg eval `ssh-agent -s` for Bourne-type shells such as sh(1) or ksh(1) and eval `ssh-agent -c` for csh(1) and derivatives.

The first option would be to remove the `eval ssh-agent` and call `ssh-agent your-script` instead.
The second option is to add the missing `$(` ... `)` to capture `ssh-agent`'s output as input for eval, as explained in [RalfFriedl's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/931026/107918).

Comment: fantastic, I have no clue how I misinterpreted that when I was reading through. Would it be wrong to assume it maybe better, if I was trying to write a script including the ssh-agent that it may be best to define a function earlier in the script then do `ssh-agent <function>`?

Comment: I like your thinking, but alas, ssh-agent is a separate program and would have no visibility of that function.

Answer (score 1):

Starting an `ssh-agent` from outside the script is what I would also recommend, that way your script runs without needing a passphrase.

But if you want to start an agent for your script, the way to do it is

```
eval $(ssh-agent)
```

After that, you can add keys to the agent and use the agent for login.

Answer (score 0):

After some checking and rechecking I seem to have found a solution but I am still interested in making this work in script. I was able to get the script to work by deploying ssh-agent and ssh-add before running my script and removing all mentions of ssh-agent related commands (specifically lines 1 & 2 in my example). SSH uses the agent variables set by me outside of the script and successfully authenticates with the key.

Downside: I still don't know how to make it create the ssh-agent session within the shell script and continue to use that agent session with the for loop.